# Crystal Report is working on LocalHost but not on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am working with crystal report in local host and it seems to be working fine but when i publish the website it doesn't take count to publish crystal report file and when i copied it to the location from my project it seems not to be working. I am not finding anything related to this on google.

This is the code I am using

```
Function Print()
            Dim rptH As ReportClass = New ReportClass
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim sSql As String
            sSql = "EXEC SP_MEDICINE_BILL 1,2014,1,104493,' ',' '"
            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sSql, conn)
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 300
            da.Fill(ds, "SP_MEDICINE_BILL")
            rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MedicineBillDoc.rpt")
            rptH.Load()
            rptH.SetDataSource(ds)
            Dim stream As Stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
            Return File(stream, "application/pdf")
        End Function
```

Comment: I have done something like this before, but I needed a virtual directory to do this. How does the process know where to pick the pdf file from?? I cant see that in your code.

Comment: I have given the path Name `~/Reports/MedicineBillDoc.rpt` it exports to stream and then stream return a file

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution I figured out problem is not server side or programming related problem. I need to set the build action property of crystal reports to content and it started working fine